# How to synchronize 'Saved Searches' to an other Thunderbird instance

Tags: thunderbird

The [Saved Searches](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/using-saved-searches) of Thunderbird are really a nice feature. Normally I'm working on several workstations using several Thunderbird instances. Is there a way to synchronize the Saves Searches between to Thunderbird instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. Copy the file `~/.thunderbird/[your profile]/virtualFolders.dat` to the other instance and reopen (the other) Thunderbird. However, the `virtualFolders.dat` file refers to your entire folder structure, so these need to be the same as well, as far as the search is concerned.

Note that this will overwrite the saved searches in the other profile. If you need to merge saved searches, you will have to open both the .dat files and copy/paste searches. It is a human readable file, so that should be easy.